# can i use 2 scalar variables for the one value in an sql query

Tags: asp.net

I have declared 2 scalar variables from a drop down list: Year and Month and in the database these are joined eg: '11A'. Im just looking to set a grid view select command so it will read this value from the database but its throwing an error with:

```
[Cycle] = @Year & @Month
```

Im not sure if this is the right way to do this as I've never used scalar variables before. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them like:

```
@val = @Year + @Month;

[Cycle] = @val
```

Comment: where in the asp page would I do this?